# Why is my promoted widget not able to use base class functions?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been trying to make a text edit be able to have its font be able to be changed along with things such as bold and italics. I tried to do so by promoting the text edit and combobox to add the font methods but I get an error C2039 'setText' is not a member of 'Editor' the promoted widget class of the textedit. I promoted it in designer to add slots for bold and italics. I set the baseclass but it cannot do some of the basic things from that class. How do I fix this?

editor.h

```
#ifndef EDITOR_H
#define EDITOR_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
class Editor: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Editor(QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // EDITOR_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTextStream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}


void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
        ...
        //Line with error
        ui->texteditor->setText(in.readAll());
        file.close();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
             ....
            //other line with error
            stream << ui->texteditor->toPlainText();
            stream.flush();
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You do not need to inherit widget in order to change it's font. `QWidget` already have all necessary methods. 2. How are we supposed to help you without any piece of source code provided? What is `Editor`? How is it defined? How is it promoted? Is it's header's directory added to `INCLUDEPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `QTextEdit` cannot be promoted to an `Editor` if `Editor` does not inherit from `QTextEdit`.  Promotion relies on standard C++ inheritance.  You are trying to create a common class that can be used to bolt on functionality to several existing widget types.  This is not possible unless you change a common base class of the widgets you are trying to add functionality to (likely `QWidget`).

Some of the choices to add `setItalic` and `setBold` slots to a set of widgets are:

1. Change the Qt source code to add the new functionality to a common base class of the `QTextEdit` and `QComboBox`
2. Make a new `Editor` class for each widget you want to extend that derives from each respective class.
3. Do not rely on inheritance to solve the problem.

1 is a terrible solution for a lot of reasons so I won't even talk about it.  2 will work if you have just a few widget types you want to have the extended functionality for, otherwise it could require a lot of duplicate code.

However, I think the best way may be to just do a little extra work in the signal handler for whatever signals you want to set the italic and bold settings.

I'm guessing you are just wanting to be able to write:

```
connect(<some_object>, <some_signal>, ui->textEdit, SLOT(setItalic(bool)));
```

Maybe instead of a direct connection, just write a quick function that doesn't rely on there being special functions for `setBold` and `setItalic`, but just uses the standard `QWidget` facilities:

```
connect(<some_object>, <some_signal>, this, SLOT(on_some_signal()));

//...

void on_some_signal()
{
    QFont fnt = ui->textEdit->font();
    fnt.setItalic(true);
    ui->textEdit->setFont(fnt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your text editor inheriting QWidget, not QTextEdit. In your editor.h file, change to:

```
class Editor: public QTextEdit
{
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a bolt-on class that can provide functionality to many other classes, you can make use of the template system:

```
class BoltOnBase {
  QWidget * const m_base;
  explicit BoltOnBase(QWidget * base) : m_base(base) { ... }
  ...
  // things that don't depend on the underlying widget type
};

template <class Base>
class BoltOn : public Base, public BoltOnBase {
  ...
pulic:
  BoltOn(QWidget * parent = 0) : Base(parent), BoltOnBase(this) {}
  ...
};

...
BoltOn<QTextEditor> myEditor;
```